# Configure client-side DNS?

Tags: networking, dns

I have a network with 2 machines. machine A has IP 192.168.1.100 , machine B has
IP 192.168.1.101. Now i want to resolve machine B IP address to test. I don't want to pass
through a dns server. 
Instead I want to modify  /etc/hosts, /etc/resolv.conf ... so that when I type "test" on machine's A browser, I am directed to machine B . Is this approach feasible and if yes, how.

Answer (score 0):

Edit you `/etc/hosts` and below put like fallow

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       xxx.yyy.com        xxx

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

192.168.1.101    test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying Machine A's `/etc/hosts` file.

Open the file and add the following:

```
192.168.1.101  test
```

Now you can reach Machine B by just using hostname `test`, you can also add an alias like:

```
192.168.1.101  test  machine-b
```

Also make sure the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file's `hosts` database lookup starts with the `files` data source. For example, in my computer:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

This means that while doing hostname resolution the relevant files in the `/etc` directory will be checked first.